# What is the proper connection string to SQL Server using Perl?

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl

I feel like a bonehead asking this question, but I have scoured the net and can't actually find a working connection string to connect Perl to SQL Server.  I've checked connectinstrings website and still couldn't find anything clear. Someone here has got to know!

I'd prefer to use DBI, but would use another library if someone else has an alternative.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perldbiconnect.php -- Scroll down until you see 'PERL - DBI Connect'

Comment: The Tiztag Perl tutorial isn't very good (see http://perl-tutorial.org/rejected/tizag/ for details). I can't see any obvious errors on this page, but linking to it gives it a credibility that it doesn't deserve.

Answer (score 1):

```
DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=192.168.1.102;UID=$user;PWD=$pass")
```

Also see: [Connecting Perl to SQL Server](http://dolio.lh.net/~apw/doc/HOWTO/HOWTO-Connect_Perl_to_SQL_Server.pdf)